# I can't get click event working in CKEditor after switching to Source mode and back

Tags: event-handling, click, ckeditor

I set event handler inside the iframe of a CKEdtor as below:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function() {
  $('.cke_contents iframe').contents().click(function() {
    alert('Clicked!');
  });
});
```

It works well, but when I click 'Source' button, it doesn't work any more (alert not working).

Someone can help me???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', { });
editor.on("pluginsLoaded", function( event ) {
    editor.on( 'contentDom', function( ) {
        var editable = editor.editable();
        editable.attachListener( editable, 'click', function( evt ) {
            console.log('click' );
        }, null, null, 10 );
    } );
} );
```

You need to use `contentDom` event if you want to keep click listener when switching to Source mode and back - https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-contentDom.

Please note that you should attach the listener to `editable` instead of `iframe` and you don't need jQuery for that.